# Spring - List of bean references from properties files?

Tags: java, spring

I have this:

```
<bean class="...">
    <constructor-arg name="beans">
        <list>
            <ref bean="beanA" />
            <ref bean="beanB" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I want to configure the list via a properties file, something like:

```
Properties file:
beans=beanA,beanB


XML file:
<bean class="...">
    <constructor-arg name="beans">
        <list refs="${beans}" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Is something like this possible with Spring?

**Edit:** Just to give some context in case there are alternative solutions to the problem, this is for an application that has to write to multiple databases, and I want to configure which databases are enabled in the properties file, so that I don't have to maintain separate XML files for dev/production.

Answer (score 0):

My first though is to use a FactoryBean where you inject the property ${beans} and the application context. Then in the factory bean, you loop on on every bean id/name and you call the context to retrieve the bean by name/id. Then you constructs your bean with your constructor and the list you have just built.

Answer (score -1):

use annotation i.e.

```
@Value("${beans}") 
private Class<? extends YourBean>String[] beanList;
```

Comment: This doesn't compile, sorry